# How can we have test my socket web server?

Tags: sockets, web, socket.io, serversocket

Hello any one can say me How can we have test my socket web server ?

i was success Run socket in my local server. http://localhost:8000

but i want to upload in live web server and test it.

any one can say me steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Frant-side

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
    var socket = io('http://localhost:8000');
    socket.emit('client_emit', { user_id: 9 });  
    socket.on('server_emit', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
    });
</script>
```

=================================================

**Node js**

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('client_emit', function (data) {
        var biker_id = "select * from user_id " + data.user_id + " LIMIT 1";
        con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
            if (err) { console.log(err); return; }
            io.sockets.emit('server_emit', result);
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: here is simple example of node js with Frant-side and back-end side please try this